# How to share common Spring application properties in multi Maven modules?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The goal is to keep some common application properties in a single file, which serves as the defaults. And these properties can be overridden by other modules, e.g. during testing, activating various profiles, command line arguments, etc.

I tried using `spring.config.import: file:..\common.yml` in each properties files I have inside each module. This worked when compiling the code as the file is placed in the parent folder of the modules. But this didn't work when executing the final jar because this common.yml is not packaged into the jar file.

Another issue I have is some nested properties get merged together. e.g.

common.yml

```
value1: default value 1
value2: default value 2
nested:
  value1: default value 1
  value2: default value 2
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    import: file:..\common.yml
---
value1: new value 1
nested:
  value1: new value 1
```

What I ended up is

```
value1 = new value 1
value2 = default value 2 <-- this is OK because value2 is not redefined in application.yml
nested.value1 = new value 1
nested.value2 = default value 2 <-- this is NOT OK as nested is redefined in application.yml to have just nested.value1
```

I do not want to have the merging behaviour for nested objects, as they are like grouped values that go together. While I DO require this merging behaviour for those non-nested objects.

So two issues here:

1. Where should I put the common.yml so that:

   1. it is included in the final jar
   2. it is referenceable by each modules
2. How do you resolve the partial nested properties being merged together?